# Convert datetime to timestamp milliseconds adding +1 month

Tags: angularjs, datetime, highcharts

high chart not rendering in IE and Safari, and solution for this problem is converting my date from API to time stamp in `milliseconds`.
here is code for convert

```
var date = '2017-06-07 10:00:00'

var d = date.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/)
console.log(d)
var parsed = +(new Date(d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6]).getTime())
console.log("timestamp: " + parsed) // 1499414400000 ==> July 7, 2017 8:00:00 AM
```

But I allways get +1 month
here is example
[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zt1k31sf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the moth count start with zero you can see here the full explanation:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please check it out this can be your perfect solution

```
const date = '2017-06-07 10:00:00'  
const d = date.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/)
var dates = new Date(d[0])
const parsed = new Date(dates).getTime()
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [[parsed, 10]]
    }]
});
```

Comment: very interesting solution :) thnx

Answer (score 0):

thnx to all, here is how I fix this.

```
var date = '2017-06-07 10:00:00'

var d = date.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/)
var parsed = new Date(d[1], d[2]-1, d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6]).getTime() //I added -1 for month

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
series: [{
    data: [[parsed, 10]]
}]
});
```